# Templates, variadic function, universal references and function pointer : an explosive cocktail

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, variadic-templates

Consider the following code and the `apply` function :

```
// Include
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

// Just a small class to illustrate my question
template <typename Type, unsigned int Size>
class Array
{
    // Class body (forget that, this is just for the example)
    public:
        template <class... Args> Array(const Args&... args) : _data({{args...}}) {;}
        inline Type& operator[](unsigned int i) {return _data[i];}
        inline const Type& operator[](unsigned int i) const {return _data[i];}
        inline std::string str() 
        { 
            std::ostringstream oss; 
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Size; ++i) 
                oss<<((*this)[i])<<" "; 
            return oss.str();
        }
    protected:
        std::array<Type, Size> _data;
    // Apply declaration
    public:
        template <typename Return, 
                  typename SameType, 
                  class... Args, 
                  class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::decay<SameType>::type, Type>::value>::type> 
        inline Array<Return, Size> apply(Return (*f)(SameType&&, Args&&...), const Array<Args, Size>&... args) const;
}; 

// Apply definition
template <typename Type, unsigned int Size>
template <typename Return, typename SameType, class... Args, class> 
inline Array<Return, Size> Array<Type, Size>::
apply(Return (*f)(SameType&&, Args&&...), const Array<Args, Size>&... args) const
{
    Array<Return, Size> result; 
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
        result[i] = f((*this)[i], args[i]...);
    }
    return result;
}

// Example
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Array<int, 3> x(1, 2, 3);
    std::cout<<x.str()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<x.apply(std::sin).str()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation fails with :

```
universalref.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
universalref.cpp:45:32: erreur: no matching function for call to ‘Array<int, 3u>::apply(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
universalref.cpp:45:32: note: candidate is:
universalref.cpp:24:200: note: template<class Return, class SameType, class ... Args, class> Array<Return, Size> Array::apply(Return (*)(SameType&&, Args&& ...), const Array<Args, Size>& ...) const [with Return = Return; SameType = SameType; Args = {Args ...}; <template-parameter-2-4> = <template-parameter-1-4>; Type = int; unsigned int Size = 3u]
universalref.cpp:24:200: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
universalref.cpp:45:32: note:   mismatched types ‘SameType&&’ and ‘long double’
universalref.cpp:45:32: note:   mismatched types ‘SameType&&’ and ‘float’
universalref.cpp:45:32: note:   mismatched types ‘SameType&&’ and ‘double’
universalref.cpp:45:32: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘Return’
```

I am not very sure why it fails.
In that code, I would like :

- to keep universal references to have the most generic function
- to be able to use the syntax `apply(std::sin)`

So what do I have to change to make it compile ?

Comment: `std::sin` doesn't have an overload that takes `int`, which is what `apply` is trying to match on with `SameType`, if I'm not mistaken. EDIT: But changing it to, e.g. `double` doesn't help either, apparently because of the universal reference...

Comment: I honestly don't understand why you want to restrict the parameter type for the function, or why you want to restrict it to a function pointer at all. Care to enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Several overloads exist](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) of function `std::sin`, and your function template has no way of deducing one that would produce an **exact match** (in most situations, no conversions are not considered when deducing template arguments).

First of all, none of those overlads accepts a *reference* to their first (and only) argument. The compiler is telling you this, so `Return` and `SameType` cannot be deduced from the type of argument `f`:

```
universalref.cpp:24:200: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
universalref.cpp:45:32: note:   mismatched types ‘SameType&&’ and ‘long double’
universalref.cpp:45:32: note:   mismatched types ‘SameType&&’ and ‘float’
universalref.cpp:45:32: note:   mismatched types ‘SameType&&’ and ‘double’
```

Therefore, the first step consists in changing the signature of your `apply()` function template:

```
[...] apply(Return (*f)(SameType, Args&&...), [...]
                        ^^^^^^^^
                        No URef!
```

Moreover, SFINAE is eliminating all instantiations of your function template where `Return` is not deduced to be `int` (you are invoking `apply()` on an instance of `Array<int, 3>`): unfortunately, none of the existing overloads of `std::sin` has `int` as a return type.

You could try changing your instantiation into `Array<double, 3>`, but that alone won't help unfortunately, because of what Paragraph 14.8.2/5 of the C++11 Standard states:

> The **non-deduced contexts** are:
>
> — The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a qualified-id.
>
> — A non-type template argument or an array bound in which a subexpression references a template
>   parameter.
>
> — A template parameter used in the parameter type of a function parameter that has a default argument
>   that is being used in the call for which argument deduction is being done.
>
> — A **function parameter** for which argument deduction cannot be done because the associated function
>   argument is a function, or a **set of overloaded functions** (13.4), and one or more of the following apply:
>
> > — more than one function matches the function parameter type (resulting in an ambiguous deduction), or
> >
> > — no function matches the function parameter type, or
> >
> > — **the set of functions supplied as an argument contains one or more function templates**.

Because of the overloads requiring *integral* types to be supported (this is new in C+11, see 26.8/11), your library implementation most likely *does* define a template overload for `std::sin`. This is how stdlibc++'s definition looks like:

```
template<typename _Tp>
inline _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR
typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<__is_integer<_Tp>::__value, 
                                double>::__type
sin(_Tp __x)
{ return __builtin_sin(__x); }
```

There are ways to get out of here, but you probably would not like them. Apart from the above necessary (yet insufficient) changes, you would also need to explicitly cast `std::sin` to the desired type. I will also drop the SFINAE condition here, because it does not do anything else than enforcing `SameType` to be equal to `Type`:

```
// Declaration in the `Array` class
template <typename Return, class... Args>
inline Array<Return, Size> apply(
    Return (*f)(Type, Args&&...), 
    const Array<Args, Size>&... args
    ) const;

[...]

// Example
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Array<double, 3> x(1, 2, 3);
    //    ^^^^^^
    //    NOTICE
    //     THIS

    std::cout<<x.str()<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<x.apply((double(*)(double))std::sin).str()<<std::endl; // OK
    //                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //                     NOTICE THIS

    return 0;
}
```